# How to Drive Particles with Global Scaling

Tags: animation, particles, transforms, scale

Below is an image of a simple particle system. As I move the particle system along the Y-axis **the particles retain their global Y position**.

[image: moving particle system]

This is all well and good and I believe it is the default behavior for such particles, however, I have come across a situation where I need a similar behavior but for scaling.

Below is an image of a similar test, but for scaling. You will notice that *all* the particles change size, and to the same size:

[image]

I am currently changing the size using the following "size" parameter in the "render" section of the particles tab:

[image]

Basically, I want to affect the particle size, *but only* for the current particles that are being spawned, after spawning the particle it should retain its size until it is killed.

I have searched the internet far and wide and either there are no good answers about this subject or I simply do not know the correct terms to search. I have dealt with similar workings in game engines and usually, this behavior is called "world transform scaling" because after being spawned the scale is not affected by the emitter.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could try this workaround https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108683/15543

Comment: This is a limitation of the current particle system in the blender. With texture, you can control the particle size ONLY with respect to the location e.g with blend texture you can make them bigger from where they are starting and smaller at the end location.